# How to return package name from txt file on server

Tags: java, android, string, text, android-asynctask

So I have an activity that goes to my server a fetches a text file. This text file holds one line of text containing a package name. My goal is to fetch the package name then use the package name to get the versionCode of the package specified in the txt file on the server. 
Here is the class that fetches the txt file from the server:

```
public class getter extends Activity {
Activity context;
TextView txtview;
ProgressDialog pd;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get);
    context=this;


}





public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    BackTask bt=new BackTask();
    bt.execute("http://1.2.3.4/test.txt");


}

//background process to download the file from internet
public static class BackTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Void>{
    String text="";
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        //display progress dialog

    }



    protected Void doInBackground(String...params){
        URL url;
        try {
            //create url object to point to the file location on internet
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            //make a request to server
            HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            //get InputStream instance
            InputStream is=con.getInputStream();
            //create BufferedReader object
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            //read content of the file line by line
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                text+=line;
            }

            br.close();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //close dialog if error occurs

        }

        return null;

    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        String packageName = text;


    }


}
public String getPackageName(Context mContext) {
    if (mContext != null) {
        BackTask bt=new BackTask();
        bt.execute("http://1.2.3.4/test.txt");
    }
    return "";
}
}
```

And this is supposed to get the versionCode from the package specified on the server:

```
    public static int getinstVersionCode(Context mContext) {
    if (mContext != null) {
        try {
            getter.BackTask bt=new getter.BackTask();
            bt.execute("http://1.2.3.4/test.txt");
            return mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(String.valueOf(new getter.BackTask().execute("http://1.2.3.4/test.txt")), 0).versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't this return the versionCode of the package name on the server?

I think the error lies in the function below but I am not sure.

> return mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(String.valueOf(new getter.BackTask().execute("http://1.2.3.4/test.txt")), 0).versionCode;

Comment: Do you get an exception or something? Can you please describe more in detail what is happening. Also, getter.BackTask().execute returns null, where it should return the text that it got from the server. It should return a String, and not be void as you specified

Comment: You have twice `new getter.BackTask().execute("http://1.2.3.4/test.txt"))`. Why? Looks no good. Further you cannot get results from an AsyncTask in that way. You should handle the result of doInBackground in onPostExecute. Only there!

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that your variable `packageName` in `onPostExecute` is local to that method. So even if that method gets called correctly, no other method would see that value.

You could try to declare `packageName` near the top of `BackTask`, near where you declare the variable `text`.

Then change this method to:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
    packageName = text;
}
```

Disclaimer:  I have not attempted to load and run your code or this fix!

Comment: Am I calling to it correctly using:   return mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(String.valueOf(new getter.BackTask().execute("http://1.2.3.4/test.txt")), 0).versionCode;

Comment: I can't see if it's completely correct. For debugging purposes you can break up this line into several lines

`return mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(String.valueOf(new getter.BackTask().execute("http://1.2.3.4/test.txt")), 0).versionCode;`

instead of just returning it. Then you can log the output of the `execute` part before `return`. What you have now makes it hard to see whether you're reading the package name.

Comment: Also, did you see Bobby Prabowo's suggestion above? You might try that and also fix the local variable problem I mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

if the network didn't have any issue then think the issue is caused because you communicate between the **doInBackground** and **onPostExecute** using a variable inside the the **AsyncTask** => text

you should using the return value on the **doInBackground** to pass it to the **onPostExecute**

change the Asynctask to

```
//background process to download the file from internet
public static class BackTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{
    protected void onPreExecute(){
    super.onPreExecute();
    //display progress dialog

}



protected String doInBackground(String...params){
    URL url;
    String text;
    try {
        //create url object to point to the file location on internet
        url = new URL(params[0]);
        //make a request to server
        HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        //get InputStream instance
        InputStream is=con.getInputStream();
        //create BufferedReader object
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        //read content of the file line by line
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            text+=line;
        }

        br.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //close dialog if error occurs

    }

    return text;

}


protected void onPostExecute(String resultText){
    String packageName = resultText;


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have twice

```
new getter.BackTask().execute("http://1.2.3.4/test.txt")).
```

Why? Looks no good.

Further you cannot get results from an AsyncTask with

```
  String.valueOf(new getter.BackTask().execute("http://1.2.3.4/test.txt"))
```

You should handle the result of doInBackground in onPostExecute. Only there!